# Is there a way to filter string by various criteria?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to pull a list of product names. In MySQL, is there a way to filter string values in the below criteria under the Where clause?

- Product name should have more than 1 word
- Product name cannot just be a number

As a reference, I'm working with an extremely simple query:

```
FROM organization                       
JOIN product on o.id = p.id                         
JOIN customer on c.id = o.id
```

Comment: Can you show input and expected output to make a [mre] ? Are you asking for a `WHERE ... AND ...` ? Can you say where you are stuck exactly ?

Comment: I'm just pulling all products from the products table pretty much, but the problem is that the data in the table is extremely messy, and need to filter out 'fake' product names hence the two criteria. I'm asking for a Where ... And ... clause help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions.

This would select product names that are not made of numbers only, and that contain at least one space (thus having more than 1 word) :

```
WHERE `product_name` NOT REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]*$'
AND `product_name` REGEXP '[[:space:]]+'
```

More info on how to use regular expressions [on that website](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook/0596001452/ch04s08.html).

Comment: Why do you assume the words are only separated by spaces?

Comment: I mean, he can ajust the regex to suit whatever he needs. His question is kinda vague.